# Strophe JS subscribe callback gets called only once

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe, openfire, strophe

I am using Strophe JS & Openfire to do simple pubsub.

**Setup :**

- OS: Windows 7
- Openfire : 3.7.0
- Strophe JS,Strophe plugin for pubsub.
- Tomcat 6:Serving webpage

**Use case:**

---

Two browser Window with two different user session(xmpp session)

Firefox(user1)---->Publisher

Chrome(user2)---->Subscriber

Code:

```
 //XConn represents Strophe Connection
//creating PUBSUB NODE (Firefox)
XConn.pubsub.createNode(
   XConn.jid,
   'pubsub.localhost',
   'PUBSUB_NODE',
   {},
    function (){ 
    }
 );

 //Adding subscriber to created node  (Chrome)
  XConn.pubsub.subscribe(
  XConn.jid,
  'pubsub.localhost',
  'PUBSUB_NODE',
  [],
  function(msg){ console.log(msg);},
  function(sub){ }
   );

   //publishing item to node (Firefox)
   XConn.pubsub.publish(XConn.jid,'pubsub.localhost','PUBSUB_NODE',[ '<item><book xmlns="pubsub:test:book"><title>Book1</title></book></item>']);
  XConn.pubsub.publish(XConn.jid,'pubsub.localhost','PUBSUB_NODE',[ '<item><book    xmlns="pubsub:test:book"><title>Book2</title></book></item>']);
```

I am expecting that both the messages published by publisher(firefox) should get printed on chrome(subscriber) console. But it just prints the first one, looks like Subscribe-callback gets called only once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the problem with subscription call back.
Strophe JS plugin(pubsub) requires to return 'true' from callback if interested to get more triggers.

So changing call-back to return true worked.

Code change to above snippet :

```
 //Adding subscriber to created node  (Chrome)
 XConn.pubsub.subscribe(
    XConn.jid,
   'pubsub.localhost',
   'PUBSUB_NODE',
    [],
    function(msg){ console.log(msg); return true; },
    function(sub){ return true;}
 );
```